# What setup do I need to do to use JSR-303 annotations with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I downloaded spring 3 and put it on my classpath but I'm not able to import the @Valid annotation. However, I am able to import other spring 3 annotations (such as @Controller). What Jar is @Valid in and what package?

EDIT: This is a JSR-303 annotation. What does that mean and how do I get it?

Comment: maybe this will help, although it's not Spring: http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/jsr-303.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

javax.validation is missing.

You'll find a jar [here](http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/). If you use Maven, this is the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

For validation to actually work, you need an implementation as well, such as [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html). Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The JSR reference means that this is a standard developed by the [Java Community Process](http://jcp.org/), specifically [JSR number 303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303).

Answer (score 9):

Just for completeness, now it's also available the next versión of the spec, that's it JSR 349, which can be obtained with:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

[Hibernate Validator 5.x](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) is the reference implementation for JSR 349 - Bean Validation 1.1 of which Red Hat is the specification lead.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get it from [hibernate-validator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/).

Answer (score 2):

It's not a spring annotation, it's from `javaee` and goes by [javax.validation.Valid](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/Valid.html), hence the JSR reference.